# Cannot resolve symbol core while importing OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, opencv3.1

I am trying to import `openCV` version `3.1.0` into `android studio` and have followed several tutorials on this but every time I try it never lets me import anything from `openCV` libraries so idk if I am setting everything up correctly or not

The error I get when trying to `import org.opencv.core.Core` is that it cannot resolve symbol Core